# EPPlus autofilter only working on last cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I would like each cell in the header to contain an autofilter. Below is the code I'm trying to use however the `autofilter` only gets set on the last cell specified.

For example, if I comment out the `autofilter` command for `K1`, the spreadsheet will be created with `C1` being the only cell with an autofilter.

```
        //Headers
        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "ChannelCode";
        ws.Cells["A1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "DrmTerrDesc";
        ws.Cells["B1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "IndDistrnId";
        ws.Cells["C1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "StateCode";
        ws.Cells["D1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["E1"].Value = "ZipCode";
        ws.Cells["E1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["F1"].Value = "EndDate";
        ws.Cells["F1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["G1"].Value = "EffectiveDate";
        ws.Cells["G1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["H1"].Value = "LastUpdateId";
        ws.Cells["H1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["I1"].Value = "ErrorCodes";
        ws.Cells["I1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["J1"].Value = "Status";
        ws.Cells["J1"].AutoFilter = true;
        ws.Cells["K1"].Value = "Id";
        ws.Cells["K1"].AutoFilter = true;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

EPPlus `.AutoFilter` is a little buggy... I suggest doing it using a range like this:

```
ws.Cells["A1:K1"].AutoFilter = true;
```

Answer (score 25):

For all sheet data range

```
worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFilter=true;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you have a dynamic set of columns, or they are defined in an array or list:

```
string[] columns = new string[] { "Name", "City", "Street" };

worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, columns.Length].AutoFilter = true;
```

The overload used is as follows:

```
public ExcelRange this[int FromRow, int FromCol, int ToRow, int ToCol] { get; }
```

I personally prefer this instead of converting an integer (columns.Length) to an Excel range with characters (for ex. "A1:C1").

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do something like this:

```
var colNames = new List<string>() { "MyCol1", "MyCol2", "MyCol3" };
var row = 3;
var startCol = 5;
var lastCol = startCol + colNames.Count - 1;
 var i = startCol; // col index

foreach (var colName in colNames)
{
   sheetObj.Cells[row, i].Value = colName;
   sheetObj.Cells[row, i++].AutoFilter= true;
}
```

... it wont work because of what to me seems to be a buggy behaviour in the implementation of `.AutoFilter`.
Even this wont work either:

```
foreach (var colName in colNames)
   sheetObj.Cells[row, i++].Value = colName;

using ExcelRange range = sheetObj.Cells[row, startCol, row, lastCol];
range.AutoFilter = true;
```

So what I found it worked to me was:

```
foreach (var colName in colNames)
    sheetObj.Cells[row, i++].Value = colName;

sheetObj.Cells[row, startCol, row, lastCol].AutoFilter = true;
```

And in case you want to make some other settings to the cells, you could do this:

```
var colNames = new List<string>() { "MyCol1", "MyCol2", "MyCol3" };
var row = 3;
var startCol = 5;
var lastCol = startCol + colNames.Count - 1;
var i = startCol; // col index

foreach (var colName in colNames)
    sheetObj.Cells[row, i++].Value = colName;

using ExcelRange range = sheetObj.Cells[row, startCol, row, lastCol];
range.Style.Font.Size = 16;
range.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
range.AutoFitColumns();
range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightBlue);

sheetObj.Cells[row, startCol, row, lastCol].AutoFilter = true;
```